# How do I apply a delay to messages on a FIFO SQS?

Tags: spring-cloud-aws

Using `'io.awspring.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-aws-messaging'` how can we apply a per-queue delay to the messages in the queue?

When I do the following...

```
sqsTemplate.convertAndSend( "myqueue.fifo", myObject, Map.of(SQS_GROUP_ID_HEADER, id, SQS_DEDUPLICATION_ID_HEADER, UUID.randomUUID().toString(), SQS_DELAY_HEADER, 1 )
```

I see...

```
org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException: Value 1 for parameter DelaySeconds is invalid. Reason: The request include parameter that is not valid for this queue type.
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-delay-queues.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The delay is set on the FIFO itself not via the service consuming it.
[image]